# Animate div detect top or bottom of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my div to animate when that div is almost half while scrolling.
How can I do it? It's not on a fixed div but its like sticky sidebar
Just like on this website [sample](http://www.lazada.com.ph/apple/)

this is my code

```
$(function(){ // document ready
   if ($('.filter-container').length) { // make sure ".filter-container" element exists
      var el = $('.filter-container');
      var stickyTop = $('.filter-container').offset().top; // returns number
      var stickyHeight = $('.filter-container').height();

      $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
          var limit = $('#footer').offset().top - stickyHeight - 100;

          var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

          if (stickyTop < windowTop){
             el.css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0, width: 280 });

          }
          else {
             el.css({ position: 'static', width: 280 });

          }

          if (limit < windowTop) {
          var diff = limit - windowTop;
          el.css({top: diff});

          }
        });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a jQuery function using [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/).

Or more easily (in my opinion) but with higher payload cost use Bootstrap affix. In this case you keep your current css but then add some Bootstrap properties to the div, in your case:

```
<div class="filter-container" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
```

This will add the classes .affix-top to the div UNTIL the user scrolls past 60px. Then if will change to .affix when the user gets 200px from the bottom it will change to .affix-bottom to the class.

This jsfiddle shows it quite well:

http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/df8tb/

This shows the appropriate css to get the sticky effect.